# How do I solve a "view not found" exception in asp.net core mvc project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm trying to create a ASP.NET Core MVC test app running on OSX using VS Code.
I'm getting a 'view not found' exception when accessing the default Home/index (or any other views I tried).

This is the Startup configuration

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app) {

        // use for development
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseDefaultFiles();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseMvc( routes => {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}"
            );
        });
    }
```

And I have the view defined in `Views/Home/index.cshtml`, and I have the following packages included on project.json

```
"dependencies": {
"Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
  "version": "1.0.0-rc2-3002702",
  "type": "platform"
},
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools" : "1.0.0-preview1-final",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "1.0.0-rc2-final"
},
```

And finally, this is the exception I get.

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The view 'Index' was not found. The following locations were searched:
    /Views/Home/Index.cshtml
    /Views/Shared/Index.cshtml
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewEngines.ViewEngineResult.EnsureSuccessful(IEnumerable`1 originalLocations)
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewResult.<ExecuteResultAsync>d__26.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- ...
```

Any suggestions of what I might be missing ?

Comment: Please, show us code from your HomeController.

Comment: And check file name -> **i**ndex.cshtml -> **I**ndex.cshtml

Comment: i exclude the view and include again in to project and probleb solved!!!!

Comment: @NimaTalebi 's solution did the trick for me!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I found this missing piece. I ended up creating a ASP.NET Core project in VS2015 and then compare for differences. It turns out I was missing `.UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())` from `WebHostBuilder` in main.

After adding this:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    new WebHostBuilder()
        .UseKestrel()
        .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .Build()
        .Run();
}
```

I then got an exception regarding missing `preserveCompilationContext`. Once added in project.json my view shows correct.

```
"buildOptions": {
    "preserveCompilationContext": true,
    "emitEntryPoint": true
},
```

Comment: In Ubuntu 16.04, calling `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` in some situations returns simple `"/"`.
Use `PlatformServices.Default.Application.ApplicationBasePath` instead for cross platform support from namespace `Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions`

Answer (score 77):

In my case, the build action was somehow changed to **Embedded resource** which is not included in published files.

Changing `Embedded resource` to `Content` resolves my issue.

[image]

Comment: I had a related issue. When I first created the file, it type a wrong extension. Because of that, Visual Studio set the Build Action to None.

This was working normally with local debugging, but when the project was published online (webdeploy or run from package), the view was not part of the build and so it was not found at runtime.

Comment: Yes! This was my issue with ViewComponent views that couldn't be found, cshtml files were marked as Build Action = None. I had created the files using the "Add New File" VS plug in which obvs doesn't set the file properties up correctly.

Answer (score 24):

I just upgraded from .net core 2.2 to 3. Two ways to resolve I found:

Either call `AddRazorRuntimeCompilation()` when configuring mvc, like:

```
services.AddControllersWithViews()
    .AddRazorRuntimeCompilation(...);
```

more info here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#opt-in-to-runtime-compilation

Or remove the following lines from the .csproj:

```
<RazorCompileOnBuild>false</RazorCompileOnBuild>
<RazorCompileOnPublish>false</RazorCompileOnPublish>
```

Comment: This worked for a 2.2 to 3.1.2 upgrade as well. Thanks!

Comment: recently installed .net 8 sdk and it broke older projects in vs 2022 17.7.4.  adding this solved my issue

Answer (score 23):

Check your .csproj file. Make sure your file(s) are not listed like:

```
<ItemGroup>
   <Content Remove="Views\Extractor\Insert.cshtml" />
   <Content Remove="Views\_ViewImports.cshtml" />
</ItemGroup>
```

If it is listed like above, remove the ones you need.
Sometimes, that happens when we do right click and change build setting to Compile.

Comment: Wow that was the problem. Didnt know how it also came to my code. But after removing it. It is solved. ThaNKS

Comment: Spot on. Built Home\Index. Worked Fine. Built a few others, all "other" were set with Remove as you showed. Kept scratching my head until I stumbled upon this. Thanks for saving the day.

Answer (score 12):

The solution of my project was by 
1- Adding  AddRazorRuntimeCompilation() such as
`services.AddControllersWithViews().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();` into `StartUp ConfigureServices`.

2- and Keeping this   `<RazorCompileOnBuild>false</RazorCompileOnBuild>`

in `.csproj` .
Then Build the project.

**Updated**

Make sure you have this NuGet package added to your project:

[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation)

Comment: adding Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation fixed it for me.  Many thanks!

Comment: Worked for me too. In my case this was the result of running a Framework 4.6.2 project through the .NET Upgrade Assistant. It appears that the tool misses this requirement.

Answer (score 12):

I had the same problem in ASP.Net Core MVC (.Net 6). I simply updated my Visual Studio 2022 to the latest version which is 17.1.0 and that solved the error.

Comment: `dotnet watch run` also works using `cmd`

Comment: For us, updating the VS build tools on the build server worked. This was creating issues where the exact same msbuild command on dev machine vs build server would produce different results.

Answer (score 6):

if you are porting your project from a console app to a web app, you need to change this line in your `.csproj` file

from:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
```

to:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
```

Comment: This one works for me. Also the Application Part need to include Program.cs with some statement inside (like {})

Answer (score 5):

I have to add in project.json this:

```
"publishOptions": {
    "include": [
        "wwwroot",
        "**/*.cshtml",
        "appsettings.json",
        "web.config"
    ]
},
```

Comment: Thanks dude! Makes sense now that I think about it.

Comment: Yep, I was missing `"**/*.cshtml",`, now it's working swell!

Answer (score 4):

For anyone struggling with this, I had a different problem than all the above.
My local version worked fine, but the live production version gave this error. It turned out the Unix filenames were different from the ones showing in Windows.

Git has a nasty setting that's enabled by default: core.ignorecasegit ( you can check this setting on the commandline with `config --get core.ignorecase`)

The solution was to rename the files to something else (e.g. xxx.cs ), commit and push, then rename them back to original with the correct casing/capitalization and commit and push again.

Answer (score 4):

I am using VS2017. In my case there was the view file at the proper place (with the proper name). Then I remembered that I renamed it before, (and the VS somehow did not asked me if I wanna change all the references as usual). So I finally deleted the view, then I made it again, and this solved my problem.

Answer (score 3):

I had this same issue while building an Identity Server instance, everything worked great if I ran the project from Visual Studio but after publishing the project and running with the `dotnet` command I got the "View not found" error when Identity Server tried to serve up the Login view.  I already had verified everything else mentioned here but it still wasn't working.  I finally found that the problem was with how I Was running the `dotnet` command.  I was running it from the parent folder, one level above my Identity Server instance and this affected the content root path, for example, running this:

```
dotnet myWebFolder/MyIdentityServer.dll
```

gave me the following output when Identity Server started:

[image: Output log showing Content root path set to C:\inetpub\aspnetcore]

So, the full path of my dll in this case is `C:\inetpub\aspnetcore\myWebFolder\MyIdentityServer.dll` and I ran the `dotnet` command from the `C:\inetpub\aspnetcore\` folder.

To get the correct content root I had to make sure I ran the `dotnet` command from the same folder where the dll is, as in `dotnet MyIdentityServer.dll`.  That change gave me this output:

[image: Output log showing Content root path set to C:\inetpub\aspnetcore\myWebFolder]

Now my content root path is correct and Identity Server finds the Login views at `C:\inetpub\aspnetcore\myWebFolder\Views\Account\Login.cshtml`

Answer (score 3):

Visual Code With dotnet version 2.2.300 gave an error message, so not a runtime exception.

My controller was derived from ControllerBase instead of Controller. So, I had to change ControllerBase to Controller.

Answer (score 3):

Same issue started happening for me after we migrated from .net 2.2 to 6.
Locally it was fine but only deployed version was giving `The view 'Index' was not found` error.

It turns out `windows-latest` and `latest` visual studio in build pipeline wasn't actually mean windows 2022 and visual studio 2022 YET. And therefore published version wasn't supporting .net 6.

After specifying 2022 versions for both windows and visual studio it started working.

Here is the reference: https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/6907

Answer (score 2):

FWIW, In our case we received this error when accessing `localhost:<port>/graphql` even though the `View/GraphQL/Index.cshtml` was in the right place. We got the error because `wwwroot/bundle.js` and `wwwroot/style.js` was mistakenly not initially committed, since our `.gitignore` included `wwwroot`. Discovered it by inspecting the network traffic and seeing it was these files giving the 404 and not the `Index.cshtml` itself.

Answer (score 2):

Im my case it simply was a "forget" error...
I had the folder with view not named the same as the controller name.
Renamed the folder to the correct name.. and works...

Answer (score 2):

I also got similar error. I am using .Net Core 6.0 ASP .Net MVC project.

It was resolved just by adding following in the program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
```

You will need to add following package reference in project file

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation" Version="6.0.3" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 1):

Reply to @LukaszDev (dont think I can attach images to a comment)
My view is **I**ndex.cshtml, typo from my side. See attached screenshot

[image]

My controller is as simple as can be. I get same error for both Index and Welcome

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace app1 {

    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class HomeController : Controller {

        // default action, configured in Startup.cs route
        public IActionResult Index() {
            // handles route /home
            return View();
        }

        [Route("welcome")]
        public IActionResult WelcomeActionDoesNotHaveToMatchName() {
            // handles router /home/welcome
            return View("Welcome"); 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was from `<EnableDefaultContentItems>false</EnableDefaultContentItems>` that I had set in my csproj

Answer (score 1):

In case of someone has a similar problem.
It turned out that my csproj file has a few invalid references to my view.
I deleted any record related to my view, I removed the csproj.user file from the project directory and I reloaded the project, then I included my view. things started working.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem under Arch Linux, Visual Studio Code and .NET Core 3.1 and 5.0.

I solved it by removeing the path to the csproj-file in the build section of the `tasks.json` file:

```
"tasks": [
    {
        "label": "build",
        "command": "dotnet",
        "type": "process",
        "args": [
            "build",
            // removed the following line:
            // "${workspaceFolder}/ProjectFoo.csproj",
            "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true",
            "/consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary"
        ],
        "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

To enable runtime compilation for all environments in an existing project:

1. Install the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation NuGet package.
   Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation
2. Update the project's Startup.ConfigureServices method to include a call to AddRazorRuntimeCompilation.
   builder.Services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();

Comment: this worked for me with visual studio 2022, and dotnet sdk 8.0.2
besides this dotnet watch run command was working regardless beforehand. For me only visual studio 2022 was having problem.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing this issue when I upgraded my .net application to .net core 6.0

```
<TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
<AddRazorSupportForMvc>true</AddRazorSupportForMvc>
```

this AddRazorSupportForMvc setting helped to resolve this issue of "the-view-index-was-not-found"

Answer (score 1):

If you are using different ***areas***, don't forget to add the `[Area("Area-Name")]` attribute to the controller.That was the issue in my case.

Answer (score 1):

In TargetFramework .net6 or higher (in lower versions use startup.cs)

1- Install the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation NuGet package.

2- Add this code In Program.cs

If you use Razor Pages

```
builder.Services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
```

If you use MVC Views

```
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
```

The steps up to this point run the views correctly for the local runtime. However, you will continue to receive the view not found error on the server. To solve this, you should also follow the step below.

3- Add this in .csproj

```
<PropertyGroup>
...
...
<CopyRazorGenerateFilesToPublishDirectory>true</CopyRazorGenerateFilesToPublishDirectory>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case after migrating from Core 2.2 to 3.1 my static html file was not being found. In my startup.cs file I had to add `app.UseDefaultFiles()` just before `app.UseStaticFiles()` to make it work. So something like this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   .
   .
   .
   services.AddControllersWithViews();
   .
   .
   .
}


public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
   .
   .
   .
   app.UseDefaultFiles();
   app.UseStaticFiles();
   app.UseRouting();
   .
   .
   .
   app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
   {
          endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
          name: "default",
          pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i was also facing similar issue,took long time to fix... Solution is in .csproj if any views are with Remove then delete those entry and include those views to project in solution explorer... then actual fix is just add one test view viewfile index3.cstml and make it called from action then deploy all works well. Later can remove that extra view file. 100% it works.[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49483693/net-core-2-0-the-view-index-was-not-found/72907896#72907896)

Comment: Odd, one view randomly added three times in my csproj... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. In my case, I had to change `<CopyToOutputDirectory>Never</CopyToOutputDirectory>` to `<CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>` from the `.csproj` file

Answer (score -1):

I had this error on Ubuntu Linux and was trying to run it from the CLI for the first time, so I fixed it by running the dotnet build command with `sudo dotnet build`, so it turned out to be a permissions issue and the app started fine with `dotnet bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.0/MyApp.dll`. Sadly the build command didn't notify about the permissions issue.

Answer (score -1):

If anyone encountered this problem in VS 2022 when a new MVC ASP.NET project is created, I had to execute

`dotrun watch run` and than `Debug` the visual studio project. The problem went away.

I am not sure why doesn't dotrun start by default when in debug mode.

Answer (score -1):

i got the same error but had a different problem/solution.
i found this warning in the build output.

```
20>CSC : warning CS8785: Generator 'RazorSourceGenerator' failed to generate source. 
It will not contribute to the output and compilation errors may occur as a result. 
Exception was of type 'ArgumentException' with message 
'The hintName 'Templates_ChangeLog_cshtml.g.cs' of the added source 
file must be unique within a generator.
```

a file with the same name was linked which caused RazorSourceGenerate to stop.
after resolving that, everything worked.

Answer (score -1):

For me, I simply rebuilt the solution and it resolved (VS 2022, ASP.net Core 6 MVC):

[image]

Answer (score -1):

try to remove this code from te csproject

```
<Target Name="DisableAnalyzers" BeforeTargets="CoreCompile">
    <ItemGroup>
        <Analyzer Remove="@(Analyzer)" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Answer (score -1):

I ran the update for Visual Studio 2022, to Version 17.7.6, and it fixed the problem.