# ASP.NET Core can't find view when integrated to IIS

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-core

I have built an ASP.NET Core application and want to rollout this app on my Win2008 server. If I start the application directly in kestrel (double click on the exe which contains the main) everything works fine. However if I start the application via IIS I get the following exception:

> fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13]
>         Connection id "0HKU0DCR0LPSS": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application. System.InvalidOperationException: The view 'Login'
>   was not found. The following locations were searched:
>   /Views/Account/Login.cshtml /Views/Shared/Login.cshtml    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewEngines.ViewEngineResult.EnsureSuccessful(IEnumerable`1
>   originalLocations)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewResult.d__26.MoveNext()

Exactly this exception was already discussed in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37529040/how-do-i-solve-a-view-not-found-exception-in-asp-net-core-mvc-project). But I compared my files with the proposed solution and still get the error.

I have also noticed that a configuration file which was originally placed next to the application.exe has to be moved inside the wwwroot folder if I start the app via IIS.

Here is the content of my web.config which sits inside the wwwroot folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="..\ERMSClient.exe" arguments="" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile="..\logs\stdout" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

And this is my project.json

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.WebListener": "0.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApiExplorer": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Newtonsoft.Json": "9.0.1",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileProviderExtensions": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "System.Web.Helpers.dll": "1.0.0",
    "AutoMapper": "5.0.2",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0"
  },
  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "net461": {
      "dependencies": {
        "d3Communicator": {
          "target": "project"
        }
      }
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "Views",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },
  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [ "npm install", "bower install" ],
    "postpublish": "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%"
  }
}
```

In addition I have to mention that I have upgraded this project from ASP.NET RC1. Therefore I have perhaps an old entry or something else somewhere.

Comment: Could you share how your Web.config looks like also a snapshot of the published folder you put in IIS?

Comment: Can you share your project.json? And tell us how do you publish it

Comment: did you use wrong project template? Normally there should be an entry in your project.json which copies over the Views folder where the exe is and does the same on deployment/publish

Comment: I have published the project from VS to the filesystem and then copied to the webserver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the very very simple answer to my problem. Somehow I assumed that I have to point the physical path of my IIS site to the wwwroot directory of my ASP.NET Core project. This is not correct the physical path has to point to the full publish directory above the wwwroot.