# Self hosted ASp.net core 2.2 app, The view 'Index' was not found. The following locations were searched

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0, identityserver4

I am creating ASP.NET Core web application and hosting it via console.

I am using [IdentitySvr4 Quick Start UI](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI) and getting all the files to my project.

[image: Console Application]

Now when I start the server by running console and browse to http://localhost:44322/, I am getting error,

> InvalidOperationException: The view 'Index' was not found. The following 
>    locations were searched:
>   /Views/Home/Index.cshtml
>   /Views/Shared/Index.cshtml
>   /Pages/Shared/Index.cshtml

I have created this project as console application and added all the nugets along the way.

The webserver starts and listens on the port, but somehow the view engine does not understand.

Main Program:

```
class Program
{
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).UseKestrel()
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .UseUrls("http://*:44322")
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
}
```

Startup class:

```
public class Startup
{

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            var signingCertificate = new X509Certificate2(Helpers.GetCertificate());
            services.AddIdentityServer()
                .AddSigningCredential(new X509Certificate2(signingCertificate))
                .AddTestUsers(InMemoryConfiguration.Users().ToList())
                .AddInMemoryClients(InMemoryConfiguration.Clients().ToList())
                  .AddInMemoryApiResources(InMemoryConfiguration.ApiResources());

            services.AddMvc();


        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            loggerFactory.AddConsole();

            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

            app.UseIdentityServer();

            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();

        }
}
```

Comment: Related issues (from quick search): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37529040/how-do-i-solve-a-view-not-found-exception-in-asp-net-core-mvc-project & https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49483693/net-core-2-0-the-view-index-was-not-found. Including stack trace may help to narrowing the problem.

Comment: Also related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50632468/routing-is-not-working-with-self-hosted-web-api.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally I would not answer my question, and just add a comment , but I think this will save the devs a lot of effort and pain.

It was simple,

I edited the .csproj with Notepad++  and found following settings:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="IdentityServer4" Version="2.3.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http" Version="2.2.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="2.2.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

After refering to a webproj, just changed it to a webproj by changing the root from `"Microsoft.NET.Sdk"` , to `"Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web"`

```
 <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="IdentityServer4" Version="2.3.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http" Version="2.2.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="2.2.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

And tha's it. Not sure why all the application logic will depend on the project type (since it could be hosted any where), but works like a charm.

Comment: ``Normally I would not answer my question`` because? https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: Fyi application logic does not depend on project type but compilation does. In .net core the views are compiled into separate dll and I suppose that doesn’t happen when the project type is not web.

Comment: What Vidmantas Blazevicius said is correct. View compilation is built into the web SDK. – How did you come up with your project file and why didn’t you use an existing template for ASP.NET Core? You should also replace all your references by a version-less reference to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` to make use of version forwarding.

Comment: @poke, I started with console application and kept adding packages. Everything worked . Even the IdentityServer4 started and was listening on ports. No dramas there. Only when I added the views from the github quick start, then I had to convert it to web app , not that I wanted to.

Comment: @Simsons Thank you for answering your own question! It saved me! I have a classlibrary with controllers and views. It was not finding the views. After this change you suggested, worked like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

For me, the error was within my .csproj file. The ItemGroup content was excluding Index.cshtml. I removed this reference and now I can navigate to Index.cshtml.

```
<pre><code>
<ItemGroup>
<Content Remove="Views\Employee\Delete.cshtml" />
<Content Remove="Views\Employee\Index.cshtml" />
</ItemGroup>
</code></pre>
```

Comment: This was indead the situation for me thanks,its a shame the tooling is getting so unreabile these days this happened in 2021 btw looks like a bug may have creapt in

Answer (score 0):

I edited the .csproj

Just remove this (if is Exist)

```
"<RazorCompileOnBuild>false</RazorCompileOnBuild>"
"<RazorCompileOnPublish>false</RazorCompileOnPublish>"
```

from `<PropertyGroup>`

By default the "RazorCompileOnBuild" & "RazorCompileOnPublish" not found in `<PropertyGroup>`

Answer (score 0):

```
dotnet clean
```

fixed it for me (.NETCore 6)