# ASP.NET Core view location ignore case on linux

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

Controller:

```
 [Area("cp"), Route("[area]/[controller]"), Authorize]
 public class AuthController: Controller
```

Action:

```
[Route("login"), AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login() {return View();}
```

Real view location is `areas\cp\auth\login.cshtml` (lowercase)
I found that on linux razor engine trying to find path like this `areas\cp\Auth\Login.cshtml` (Upper letter)

And result of action is 404 NotFound.
All working find on windows.

```
 An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
 System.InvalidOperationException: The view 'Login' was not found. The 
 following locations were searched:
 /areas/cp/views/Auth/Login.cshtml <--- there is view exist
 /Areas/cp/Views/Auth/Login.cshtml 
 /Areas/cp/Views/Shared/Login.cshtml
 /Views/Shared/Login.cshtml
 /Pages/Shared/Login.cshtml
```

Enabling lowercaseurls not helped

```
services.AddRouting(options => options.LowercaseUrls = true);
```

Adding custom `IViewLocationExpander` too

```
public class ViewLocationExpander : IViewLocationExpander
{

    public IEnumerable<string> ExpandViewLocations(ViewLocationExpanderContext context, IEnumerable<string> viewLocations)
    {
        //{2} is area, {1} is controller,{0} is the action
        var locations = new[]
        {
            "areas/{2}/views/{1}/{0}.cshtml".ToLower(),
        };
        return locations.Union(viewLocations);          //Add mvc default locations after ours
    }


    public void PopulateValues(ViewLocationExpanderContext context)
    {
        context.Values["customviewlocation"] = nameof(ViewLocationExpander);
    }
}
```

How can i solve this? I dont want to rename my locations to match with upper letter

**UPD:**

I think that is the best solution for me is get implementation RazorViewEngine from asp.net git repo and add some ToLower() cases to FindView() and GetView() and register it like default engine. But is it ok about license?

Comment: This is bit of wild stab, and I'm not in a position to verify myself, but have you checked if you done the answer in this similar question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37529040/how-do-i-solve-a-view-not-found-exception-in-asp-net-core-mvc-project

Comment: I think that is the best solution for me is get implementation RazorViewEngine from asp.net git repo and add some ToLower() cases to FindView() and GetView() and register it like default engine. But is it ok about license?

Comment: You can always override default view engine or use custom view engine

Comment: How about `ViewLocationExpanderContext.ActionContext.RouteData.Values["action"] = ViewLocationExpanderContext.ActionContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToLowerInvariant()`?

Comment: You can also decorate your action with `[ActionName]` attribute that will override the action name. Or, register a global filter than will do that for all actions. Alternatively, you can have your `ActionDescriptor` that will do it in a cleaner way

Comment: @haim770 ty for your reply. can you please provide more info about how to register actionname globally?