# Cannot find view 'Index', although index is there - ASP.NET Core 6 MVC

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-6.0

I am trying to run my asp.net application on localhost, but seem to get the following error:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>
> InvalidOperationException: The view 'Index' was not found. The following locations were searched:
> /Views/Web/Index.cshtml
> /Views/Shared/Index.cshtml
> /Pages/Shared/Index.cshtml

I have my view located in `Views > Web > Index.cshtml`, although I still haven't found a way to resolve this issue. I have gone through the asp.net documentation and other stackoverflow posts. Can't seem to solve the issue.

Using:

- Visual Studio 2019
- ASP.NET Core 6
- Windows 10

Here is the code in my program.cs file

```
    using UploadExcel.Context;
    using UploadExcel.Service;
    
    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
    
    // Add services to the container.
    builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
    builder.Services.AddDbContext<DatabaseContext>();
    builder.Services.AddScoped<IWebService, WebService>();
    
    var app = builder.Build();
    
    // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    
    if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
        app.UseHsts();
    }
    
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    
    app.UseRouting();
    
    app.UseAuthorization();
    
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "default",
            pattern: "{controller=Web}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
    
    app.MapRazorPages();
    
    app.Run();
```

Comment: I have also encountered this problem, the reason is that I did not put the Index into the Web file correctly, just in the Views folder, just under the Web folder, let me think I put it into the Web folder. There is no error when the provided code puts the Index into the Web folder correctly, so I will give you two suggestions. First, check the location of the Index to see if it appears when the Web folder is pulled down and expanded, and secondly, check whether the page name corresponding to the Index method is Index.

Answer (score 12):

If you are experiencing this issue on **Visual Studio 2022**, ASP.Net Core MVC (**.NET 6**), as an immediate solution what you can do is open a terminal where your `*.csproj` file resides and execute,

```
dotnet watch run
```

If you really want to use Visual Studio then **you must update Visual Studio 2022 to version 17.1.0 +** (your current version might be 17.0.4 or something).
Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71369674/5260872) and [this](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/25157#issuecomment-1060019598).

Comment: Upgrading VS did the thing for me, thanks

Comment: And apparently it's broken again in 17.1.2. I updated to 17.2.1 and it worked fine.

Comment: Updating to 17.7 worked for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 12):

One of the causes of this problem can be the build action of the cshtml file.

- Go to the cshtml file that have this issue.
- Right click it and change properties [ or click Alt + Enter ]
- Change the property named **Build Action** from None to **Content**

As shown in the images below:

[None is selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BPDa3.png)

[Open DDL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLoQQ.png)

[Select Content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGklK.png)

Comment: Still getting this problem with VS 17.4.0. This solution was what solved it for me. However, this only happens on SOME partial views. I have tons of others that I haven't had to do this for and they work fine? Go figure?

Comment: Super strange why this would randomly happen with one view but this fix worked!

Comment: Thank you very much. I got the same problem in Visual Studio 2022.

Answer (score 3):

1. install Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation from NuGet Package Manager.

Add below lines in program.cs

2. `builder.Services.AddMvc().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();`
3. `builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();`
4. `app.MapControllers();`

Answer (score 0):

since you are using controllers you have to add

```
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
```

Answer (score 0):

For me I had to install the correct SDK.

I ran the command below

```
dotnet --list-sdks
```

realized I did not have sdk 6.0.413, install that particular sdk, ran dotnet --list-sdks again to make sure I had that version.

Then I added a global.json file to root directory to change the sdk version.

My build was working correctly. I only found out via warning error in the build logs. Once I added the global.json file I no longer got the view Index error.

Answer (score 0):

After updating visual studio to latest version it's working fine

Answer (score -6):

May be your applicaiton is opening on VS2019, please open the project in VS2022, issue will be fixed.