# InvalidOperationException: The view 'Index' was not found. The following locations were searched

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

The following error occurs when creating a new ASP.NET Core MVC project or loading old projects in .NET 7:

[image]

All the archovios are created and in the right place.

[image]

The error persists even if you manually change the route

[image]

I have searched everywhere and have not been able to find the problem.

Answer (score 17):

For anyone having this issue when updating to Visual Studio 2022 17.7.7, updating to 17.8 solved it.

Comment: Should be the accepted answer IMHO

Comment: I had the issue after upgrading from 17.5.3 to 17.8.2 which is the latest version as of writing this post. Rolled back to 17.5.3 for now.

Comment: It works. Cool!

Comment: For me upgrading my projects from .NET 7 to .NET 8 did the trick... I also updated my NuGet packages so maybe that was part of it too.. so weird and frustrating and a little scary tbh.

Comment: Currently on version 17.8.5 and the problem still exists.

Comment: @RameshVaduka: Yes. [Changing the property named `Build Action` from `None` to `Content` helped](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73589803/1369235).

Comment: I am currently having this problem on Version 17.8.7

Comment: It's still happening on 17.9.1 as well.

Answer (score 7):

1st **go to your project solution** -->Right click and add nuget Packages called
`*Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation*`  install this.

2nd **add one line on Programm.cs** file
i.e "builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews()***.AddRazorRuntimeCompilation()***;"

Answer (score 2):

> InvalidOperationException: The view 'Index' was not found. The
> following locations were searched.I have searched everywhere and have
> not been able to find the problem.

Actually, when you define `../` it means two directory down from the parent directory which means compiler would be searching views folder two directory inside your project parent directory but in really that's obviously not there. In your scenario Viwes folder actually located one directory down from the parent directory which you can seee below:

[image]

Consequently, you are getting this very exception which I have reproduced accordingly as following:

[image]

**Solution:**

You could resolve your exception by providing the correct path. You can use either of the following to get rid of your issue.

```cs
 return View("./Views/Home/Index.cshtml");
```

Note: This ./ is meaning the compiler would search Views folder one directory down from the parent directory which is the correct location.

```cs
return View("~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml");
```

Note: You can use the  [tilde ("~") operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-7.0#serve-files-from-multiple-locations) in any path-related property in server controls which would search the path.

Output:

[image]

**Note:** If you would like to know more details on [Directory browsing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-7.0#directory-browsing) you could [check our official document here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-7.0#serve-files-from-multiple-locations)

Answer (score 1):

Update the Visual Studio from **17.8.7** to version **17.9.4** solved the problem in my case.

[image]