# ASP.NET Core MVC View not found when running as a standalone application

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.2

I have a case when the startup process of an ASP.NET Core 2.2 application occurs inside a library. The application calls that library to build and run the host.

The setup code in the library adds the application itself as an ApplicationPart to ASP.NET Core MVC, so that the application could define ASP.NET Core MVC controllers and views as well.

The problem I'm facing is that a view defined in the application is found when running from visual studio or using

```
dotnet run application.csproj
```

but is not found when running the application's `.exe` file alone.

Both the library and the application have an additional views assembly (autogenerated) with the names of `LibraryName.Views.dll` and `ApplicationName.Views.dll` and both of them contains all the views inside.

The application is targeting .NET Framework 4.8

What am I missing here?

Some logging of the process. The Controller's name is "CustomStatusDialogController".

**Working** (dotnet run):

```
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewResultExecutor[1]
      Executing ViewResult, running view Index.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewResultExecutor[2]
      The view path '/Views/CustomStatusDialog/Index.cshtml' was found in 8167.5568ms.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewResultExecutor[4]
      Executed ViewResult - view Index executed in 10570.57ms.
```

**Not working** (application's .exe file)

```
...
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewResultExecutor[1]
      Executing ViewResult, running view Index.
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewResultExecutor[3]
      The view 'Index' was not found. Searched locations: /Views/LogMessages/Index.cshtml, /Views/CustomStatusDialog/Index.cshtml, /Views/Shared/Index.cshtml, /Pages/Shared/Index.cshtml
```

Thank you.

Comment: Anyone? I'm guessing it is something to do with the view engine, but I cannot find what

Answer (score 1):

If you are using .NET Core 2.x Try defining **MvcRazorCompileOnPublish** flag in your project file

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
    <MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>true</MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>
</PropertyGroup>
```

For .NET Core 3.x you can add **CopyRazorGenerateFilesToPublishDirectory**

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  <CopyRazorGenerateFilesToPublishDirectory>true</CopyRazorGenerateFilesToPublishDirectory>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Let me know if this helps

Comment: I'll check when I'll get to my computer and report back. Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work. This flag only decides if the views are compiled or not. My problem is that they do get compiled, but not found.

Comment: Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37529040/how-do-i-solve-a-view-not-found-exception-in-asp-net-core-mvc-project). May be it will help

Comment: Thank you @Pathik Patel,  tryed to exclude the view and include it back again and still did not work. I even started a new application with this setup and still the problem occurrs.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `<AddRazorSupportForMvc>true</AddRazorSupportForMvc>` in the library's .csproj file inside `<PropertyGroup>`