# How to specify a view component under a sub folder within shared/components

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor-pages

I get an error anytime I try to specify a view component from a razor page which lies anywhere but directly under the folder structure of shared/components. For example, shared/components/UserCRUD/{mycomponent} will not work. See the pictures below:

where I include the view component. Note that I have also tried this with typeof() and nameof(), to which the intellisense correctly identifies the correct location under the sub folder.

[image]

My relevant folder structure:

[image]

The namespace I am using. Note that I have also tried naming this with the "ViewComponent" suffix to no end.

[image]

And finally the exception. The most strange thing is that the exception isn't looking at the path I handed it. It's completely omitting UserCRUD.

[image]

Comment: The linked article has a few things you can try: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37529040/how-do-i-solve-a-view-not-found-exception-in-asp-net-core-mvc-project

Comment: @Kevon None of those worked for me unfortunately. The problem is also slightly as they are using a views/x folder structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The folder setup you have doesn't match with the default [view location formats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-6.0#view-search-path).
Even adjusting those doesn't seem to work - *or at least I don't succeed in it*.

No combination of fixed values and predefined [placeholders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.razor.razorviewengineoptions.areapageviewlocationformats?view=aspnetcore-6.0#remarks) (`{0}` view name, `{1}` page name) seem to give the expected result; there's something with that `Components` segment that always get added automatically.

---

Below does work.

In `AdminDashboard/Index.cshtml` include that `UserTable` component as below.
*You can also keep your current call since that one seems to work.*

```
@await Component.InvokeAsync("UserTable")
```

Adjust your `UserTable` component in `UserTable.cs` by returning the full path to the corresponding view, being `/Areas/Identity/Pages/Shared/Components/UserCRUD/UserTable/UserTable.cshtml`.

```
public class UserTable : ViewComponent
{
    public IViewComponentResult Invoke(string module)
        => View("/Areas/Identity/Pages/Shared/Components/UserCRUD/UserTable/UserTable.cshtml");
}
```

You'll have to do similarly for the other views in that `UserCRUD` folder.

Comment: This fixed it! Thanks a ton. Yeah the component segment always being added is a seriously annoying problem. It's also a bit frustrating that we have to fully specify the path to the view, but this beats sticking all of my components under a single folder!