# .Net Core 7.0 InvalidOperationException: The view 'Index' was not found. The following locations were searched

Tags: c#

[image]

Please someone help me with this exception, in development it works but when publishing it in ISS it persists, it already has Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation installed, which in development works correctly, but when publishing it in ISS it does not
I emphasize that it has **Microsoft Identity Platform authentication**

I also tried redirecting to the index with "~/Views/Home/_Index.cshtml" and it gives the same error but with the path burned.

I can't figure out what's going on, it's still in development and working properly.

**Code of program.cs**

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

DependencyInjection.GenerateService(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("sqlserver"));
var initialScopes = builder.Configuration["DownstreamApi:Scopes"]?.Split(' ') ?? builder.Configuration["MicrosoftGraph:Scopes"]?.Split(' ');
builder.Services.AddScoped<InformeCartera>();
// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
        .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(initialScopes)
            .AddMicrosoftGraph(builder.Configuration.GetSection("MicrosoftGraph"))
            .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
});

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
{
    var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .Build();
    options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
}).AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
builder.Services.AddRazorPages()
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    await DataInstances.Instances();
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
}

await DataInstances.Instances();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
app.MapRazorPages();
app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

**Code of Controlador**

```
  [Authorize]
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public string FechaInput { get; set; }
        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;

        private readonly InformeCartera _info;

        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger, InformeCartera info)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _info = info;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Fecha = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd"); ;
            return View();
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Informe(string fecha)
        {
            List<CarteraConsolidada> Informe = new List<CarteraConsolidada>();
            try
            {
                Informe = await _info.ObtenerResultados(fecha);
                ViewBag.Contador = "Número de resgistros "+ Informe.Count().ToString();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                TempData["errorMessage"] = ex.Message;
            }
            return View("Index", Informe);
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37529040/how-do-i-solve-a-view-not-found-exception-in-asp-net-core-mvc-project - does it solves your problem?